# Update UI in android App without making users to update the App

Tags: android, mobile

I am building an app using , so the first time I upload the app to playstore, it will go with pre-defined Menu options and other stuffs.

Now, suppose I want to add a menu option in the Header of the App for any festive seasons or some awesome offers, and on clicking the menu, I should display the latest offers.

Is there any way to implement this feature without having to go through the process of again uploading to appstore and making users to update the app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept of Over The Air (OTA) updates which you are referring to here. This is provided by `Expo` (by default create-react-native uses expo), firebase and Microsoft code push. You can read about it more here on [official expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html#deploying-to-the-app-store-and-play-store). If you are not using Expo then i prefer [Code Push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/)

Answer (score 0):

Build an api endpoint you call at the app startup seems to be the easiest way to do this. Take a look at firebase if you don't want to build a full api and server yourself. Cloud functions are easy to use and could do the job in your case.

Comment: Can u elaborate about the api endpoint thing? How can I actually implement?